# Bootstrap 3 Navbar - Adding Bullet Points in between list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bit of a styling issuing and trying to work out if this is possible with bootstrap 3.

Here is what the nav bar is intending to look like:
[image: final nav bar]

Ignore the colours thats the easy bit :) just I need to work out away to get these bullet points inbetween the list items (

)

Here is the furtheset progress i can get on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2s1ahekp/

Please drag the bar to make the screen bigger so you can see the nav bar.

HTML:

```
  <div id="nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><div class="bullet"></div><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><div class="bullet"></div><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><div class="bullet"></div><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><div class="bullet"></div><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><div class="bullet"></div><a href="#">Contact</a><div class="bullet"></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    background-image: url('bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    min-height: 71px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
    }

    .bullet {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
        opacity: 0.729;
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;

    }
}
```

The bullet points must not be visible when the screen switches to a responsive drop down menu (mobile).

Spent far to long working on this asking the community to see if I can get help. I have also tried to search to see if this is a problem already been solved and turned up an empty search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the bullets in your html.

[image]

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hmw6e25x/**

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar-nav {
        ...
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
        position: relative
    }
    .navbar-nav > li:before,
    .navbar-nav > li:last-child:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 6px;
        height: 6px;
        background: red;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -2px;
        right: -3px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li:before {
        right: auto;
        left: -3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you want before and after. You can probably figure it out but I will get to it.

Comment: Actually, it's more logical to do the :before on the left and the :after on the right since there are more :befores than afters but since I didn't realize you were doing both, then you will need to switch this around and learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the bullets completely and add the following class

```
a::before{
        content:"";
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
        opacity: 0.729;
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        margin:0 10px; 
        display:inline-block;

}
```

find the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z5gr9bhp/)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2s1ahekp/3/)

Note: You can use `display:inline-flex` only in `HTML5`